# In Primefaces picklist, how to find that an item is moved from TARGET to SOURCE, Using Omnifaces Converter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces

I have looked around and could not find a solution.

I am using `Omnifaces` `listConverter` in the `PickList` component of `Primefaces`. When I move an item from **SOURCE** to **TARGET**. In the backing bean i get the new item ONLY on `dualList.getTarget()`.

However when I move an item from **TARGET** to **SOURCE**. In the backing bean I am not able to check whether an item has been removed from the **TARGET**.

I tried `dualList.getSource()` - **SOURCE** does not contains the item/s dropped from **TARGET**
And off course **dualList.getTarget()** will be empty (assuming that no item is moved from SOURCE to TARGET).

*My question is how can i find that something has been moved from **TARGET** to **SOURCE** in the backing bean?*

Previously I have created a custom converter and in that, my `dualList.getTarget()` gives me the updated target (ie old values + new values added + old values removed). Therefore I can figure it out which values are added, removed and are still present.

But while using `Omnifaces listConverter` i am not understanding how to achieve it.

My code looks like this:

**XHTML**

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{assignBenchmarkersBean.dualUserList}" 
            var="users" itemLabel="#{users.username}" itemValue="#{users}" >
    <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" 
                 list="#{assignBenchmarkersBean.dualUserList.source}" />
</p:pickList>

<p:commandButton id="update" value="#{bundle.create}" 
                 styleClass="redButton bigFont" 
                 actionListener="#{assignBenchmarkersBean.update()}" />
```

**Bean**

```
public void update(){
        try{
            prepareRemoveOldAndAddNewUsersList();
           /**some other code **/
        }catch(Exception e){
            FacesMsg.error(ErrorMessage.UPDATE.getValue(), e);
        }
    }

    private void prepareRemoveOldAndAddNewUsersList() {
        for(User user : dualUserList.getTarget()){      //add users
            addUsers.add(user);
        }
        for(User user : dualUserList.getSource()){      //remove users
            if(oldUserList.contains(user)){
                removeUsers.add(user);
            }
        }
    }
```

**User entity**

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        User other = (User) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.abc.model.main.User[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
```

NOTE:

If in the converter's `list` attribute, I put `bean.dualList.target`, then the whole thing works the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I got it worked for me.

In the implementation of the Omnifaces `ListConverter`, the `getAsObject` method is using the `list` to find the value and update the `target` and `source` of `dualList`.

**NOTE**: you will get either a new value added in `target` `(List=".getSource")` or a new value added in `source` `(List=".getTarget")`, as per the `List` value you have entered.

Hence by changing the `List` from `myBean.dualList.getSource` to `myBean.completeList`, I get the updated `target` and `source` *(ie old values + new values added + old values removed )*.

If a user is only concerned with the new value added in `target` or `source` and not on if any value is removed, then he should use `myBean.dualList.getSource` and `myBean.dualList.getTarget` respectively.

However if user wants to know the final content as it is in my case, use the whole collection ie `myBean.completeList`.

In short it is the `List` which you are passing in the `<o:conveter>` tag is important.

Hope it will help!!

Answer (score 10):

It is better to use ajax `transfer` event for this goal, as described in [PrimeFaces User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation).

XHTML:

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{assignBenchmarkersBean.dualUserList}" 
        var="users" itemLabel="#{users.username}" itemValue="#{users}" >
    <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" 
             list="#{assignBenchmarkersBean.dualUserList.source}" />
    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{pickListBean.handleTransfer}" />
</p:pickList>
```

Bean:

```
public class PickListBean {
    //DualListModel code
    public void handleTransfer(TransferEvent event) {
        //event.getItems() : List of items transferred
        //event.isAdd() : Is transfer from source to target
        //event.isRemove() : Is transfer from target to source
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is a solution. But I am more concerned about why only using Omnifaces ListConverter I cannot achieve the same. In this scenario, every time a user transfers, a new ajax request is created.

Comment: I can also write a custom converter... but do not know, which way is better... custom converter or ajax:transfer approach

Comment: If throwing an ajax on every user transfer has no large permormance impact in your case, the ajax is better. It keeps code cleaner and is less error-prone. Moreover it is a native out-of-the-box solution from PrimeFaces, is part of API (thus have bug/issues support from PrimeFaces team) and you must not rely on internal implementation.